# Lock Saleae Software to Launcher

Tags: 16.04, launcher

I've tried several methods to lock the Saleae Logic Software to the Launcher, but nothing worked ... 
It's just an executable file in a folder and the program starts up without problems.

-Once started right click and click on "Lock to Launcher" first seems to work, but when I close the software the icon seems to be some kind of translucent and nothing happens when I click it.

-I have also created different `.desktop` files and nothing appeared :/

e.g.
this file is create if i chose the right click action

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Saleae Logic Software
Icon=logic
Path=/home/cain/Logic 1.2.14 (64-bit)
Exec=/home/cain/Logic 1.2.14 (64-bit)/Logic
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Logic
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

I tried some different codes with different attributes.
This is my latest with an extra downloaded png ...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Saleae Logic Software
Icon=/home/cain/Logic 1.2.14 (64-bit)/SaleaeLogic.png
Exec=/home/cain/Logic 1.2.14 (64-bit)/Logic
```

I've no clue what's going wrong an would appriciate every kind of help :)

Comment: You have spaces in your `Exec=` and `Icon=` lines. Try enclosing the entire path between `"` and `"` for both lines. Maybe you need to escape `(`, `)`, and `/` as well.

Comment: Renamed the folder in "Saleae_Logic" now everything works fine !
Thank you !!!

Comment: Great! For the future, stick to letters, numbers and maybe `-` and `_` to be on the safe side. Avoid other characters and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to work it out..
you have to link the Logic application to /usr/bin inorder to call from the terminal. My app folder was in /opt/logic1.2..

```
sudo ln -s /opt/logic1.2.18/Logic /usr/bin/logic
```

after this you should be able to run logic from command line

my logic.desktop shortcut file is as follows

```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=Saleae Logic Software
  Icon=/opt/logic1.2.18/logic.png
  Exec=/opt/logic1.2.18/Logic
  Terminal=false
  StartupWMClass=Logic
  X-UnityGenerated=true
```

use some kind of jpeg image for the icon..